# Транзакции в Mysql

Tags: mysql, база-данных, многопоточность, транзакции

При каких уровнях изоляций в mysql, одновременные запросы потоков встают в очередь?

Comment: Зависит от типа запроса (вернее, от типа обращения к таблице в запросе). В общем случае - при любых.

Comment: @Akina благодарю